# load link into slider when clicked-ajax php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink, load

i have a problem with this code
if any body can help me pls help :(
i have 2 category in database
and all 2 category have image(pic)
i want load image in image slider when user clicked on any category
code:

```
$("#test).load('test.php?name='+categoryname,function(){
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect:'random', 
animSpeed:500, 
pauseTime:3000,
});
});
```

---

html code:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <span id="test"></span>
        </div>
```

---

test.php code

```
echo "<img src='$return' alt='$des_return' title='$des_return'>"."<br>";
```

---

pls answer if anybody can help
thanks

Comment: you forgot to close you quotes around `test` as in `$("test").`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at your code quickly I can see 2 errors in your JS:

1) Line 1. `$("#test)` should be `$('#test')`

2) Line 5. Remove the comma i.e `pauseTime:3000,` -> `pauseTime:3000`

The PHP should be:

```
echo "<img src='" . $return . "' alt='" . $des_return . "' title='" . $des_return . "' /><br />";
```

Comment: thanks i do it.but just first time working and if i again click on other category slider not working :(

Comment: Do you have a link where I can see what you have?